# Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, bluebird

I'm sending a base64 encoded token to my API. It's an id token from google. When the string is valid it all works fine but i'm actually trying to setup proper error handling. Adding some extra characters to the string throws the TypeError.

I've logged the result from the encoding and the buffer and it's all defined. Anyone able to tell what i'm doing wrong?

```js
function(payload) {
  var config = request.getAsync('https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration')
    .then(function(result) {
      var response = JSON.parse(result.body);
      return request.getAsync(response.jwks_uri);
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      return JSON.parse(result.body);
    })
    .caught(SyntaxError, function(e) {
      throw e;
    })

  var header = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var segments = payload.id_token.split('.');
      try {
        resolve(JSON.parse(base64urlDecode(segments[0])));
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }

    })
    .caught(SyntaxError, function(e) {
      throw e;
    })

  return Promise.join(config, header, function(response, header) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var key = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < response.keys.length; i++) {
        if (response.keys[i].kid === header.kid) {
          key = response.keys[i];
          break;
        }
      }

      if (jws.verify(payload.id_token, key)) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  });
}

function base64urlDecode(str) {
  return new Buffer(base64urlUnescape(str), 'base64').toString();
};

function base64urlUnescape(str) {
  str += Array(5 - str.length % 4).join('=');
  return str.replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
}
```

Comment: What does it return if you `console.log(new Buffer(base64urlUnescape(str), 'base64'))` ?

Comment: Returns a buffer, doesnt say undefined. Checked the str itself after the unescape too. Does a buffer even throw errors ? Couldnt find anything online about it.

Comment: Log returns <Buffer 69 ec 89 85 b1 9c 88 e8 89 49 4c c8 d4 d8 88 b0 89 ad a5 90 88 e8 89 98 c8 c0 cd 8d 90 d0 cc cc e5 98 e5 98 c8 e4 dc d8 c8 e5 84 c9 84 e0 d8 cd 8c cc ... >

Comment: That's strange. Are you sure the stack trace points to this line exactly?

Comment: i've reduced to code to just that block and that;s where the errors happens. Went from base code and then also toggled everything back on again. Errors occurs there. The token i pass in works fine but when i add say 123 to the front it'll occur

Comment: Seems the buffer cannot handle an invalid base64 endoded string and will returned undefined when toString() is called. How do i catch this?